# Consolas smaller than Verdana

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm writing a webpage where I want to use one font for normal text and another for code, so I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
}

code, pre {
    font-family:Consolas, monospace;
}
```

This works except that the Consolas text comes out considerably smaller than the Verdana text. I can sort of fix it by adding `font-size:1.2em;` to the `code, pre` settings, but that feels like a hack, particularly since the number isn't derived from anything other than trial and error.

Is this something that happens to be a quirk of the particular fonts involved, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas this is because Consolas has a smaller x-height than Verdana. You can indeed "sort of fix it" by using a larger font size, but if the user doesn't have Consolas the page will fall back to the default monospace font, which will appear too large.

The proper solution lies in CSS3's [`font-size-adjust`](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-little-known-font-size-adjust-css3-property/). Alas it isn't very well supported at all; as far as I know then only mainstream browser to support it is Firefox.

Comment: Ah, I guess that answers that, thanks. What monospace font do people recommend using instead of Consolas, then? The one used on StackOverflow looks pretty good, which one is that?

Comment: Hmm, it seems Stack Overflow uses Consolas as first choice, but somehow gets it to be the right size. Does it use a special trick for this, or does it just hope the browser won't have to fall back to a font that would end up the wrong size?

Comment: They aren't doing anything clever as far as I can tell. Any one of the specified fonts will suffice and a slight variation in size doesn't matter a great deal in this case. The end user probably won't notice anyway!

Answer (score 2):

When you define a font-size in CSS, what you're doing is defining a concept known as an "em square" or "em box" even if you aren't using em units.

The em square gets its name because in the days of metal press printing, each letter was put in its own metal "box" and in traditional typefaces the uppercase Latin M typically filled the width of an entire box, defining the sizes for the entire family.  Hence, the em box.  Although the original em box was defined by the width of the M, the em unit itself refers to the maximum allowable *height* of a character.  This was just a result of the box created for the uppercase M.

In short, all of the letters in a font family need to fit inside the em box, but they don't have to take up the whole thing.  So when you set an em box with a given width, all you are doing is defining the maximum allowable space for the lettering to be placed in.  From there, the typeface designer's choices in kerning, geometry, ratios, etc. will determine just how much of that box their lettering will take up.  This is why you are having to use two different font sizes to make the lettering appear to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The font sizes are the same. But in Verdana, characters are generally taller than in most fonts (in the same size). For example, “H” in Verdana is taller than “H” in Consolas. This is a font design issue.

The solution is to use matching fonts. If you really want to use Verdana for copy text, Lucida Console is probably the best choice for a monospace font. If you want to use Consolas as monospace font (fine!), then use another “C font” for copy text, such as Cambria (serif font) or Calibri or Candara (sans-serif fonts).

Although the font sizes are the same here (on browsers that I tested), it is best to make sure of it, since browsers often apply something like `font-size: 90%` on `code` and `pre` and some other elements. The conditions for this to happen are somewhat obscure, and explicitly setting font family to something else than the generic `monospace` seems to prevent that on modern browsers. But it’s still a useful precaution to set

```
pre, code, samp, kbd, tt { font-size: 100%; }
```

Comment: Right; taking Verdana as reasonable baseline size (corresponds to Arial, Helvetica etc. and is much more readable size than the other C* fonts), is there any monospace font that matches it in size? I tried Lucida Console, but it wasn't much bigger than Consolas, just scrunched the lines closer together.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fonts]

The first line is in Verdana and the second is Consolas. Both 12pt. Consolas is slightly shorter, but not so much as in 20% difference. Check the parent elements of your pre, since em font sizes are cummulative - e.g. if body is 0.9em and pre is 0.9em, the result would be 12pt * 0.9 * 0.9 = 9.72pt

If you are trying to match only the height but ignoring the width, then 1.16em looks about right, and it is really the quirk of the font and you are not doing anything wrong.

**Edit**

Looks like you are doing nothing wrong =) Left is from fiddler, right is from WordPad

[image]

Comment: Ah, that does not match the results I'm getting, whereas http://jsfiddle.net/artifex/SF9su/ does, and in both my page and the linked sample, there is no other mention of font size. Maybe the key is "both 12pt" - maybe they differ in default point size? How can you ensure they are both the same?